# Using a JavaScript function to return the value as a parameter inside <asp:QueryStringParameter>

Tags: javascript, html, function, url, querystringparameter

I am using SelectParameters:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Store" DbType="String" Direction="Input" QueryStringField="Name" DefaultValue="getURL();" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
</SelectParameters>
```

My JavaScript function looks like follows:

```
function getURL() {
    var url = document.URL;
    url = url.substring(url.indexOf('=')+1, url.length);
    return url;
}
```

I am returning part from the page's URL, although it is not working.

I think the function is not executing because the parameter of "DefaultValue" is being used as a String value.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I tried DefaultValue=getURL(); (without quotation marks) and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your ASP code executes at the server, while you are trying to invoke javascript function getURL() which can only execute in a browser i.e. at client-side.

What you are trying to achieve, can't be done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you give me some advice as how to get the URL from the page to be used inside my SelectParameter ? Or is there a better way to do what it is I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm not an ASP Programmer, but I'm sure that ASP will provide some sort of Server API to fetch the request parameters i.e. parameters sent by a GET / POST request. Using such an API will help you.

In case of Java Servlets, you could achieve the same using request.getQueryString() or request.getParameter("Name")